# Update randomly selected row in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table and in it a certain value - by default it is set to -1, but I want to change it to 0 for a random row.

What is the right query for this operation?

Here is what I tried:

```
UPDATE statuses SET status = 0
WHERE word_id = (
      SELECT word_id FROM statuses WHERE status = -1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Does <http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg14657.html> help?

Comment: I am not sure, what's the problem with "ORDER BY RANDOM()"?

Comment: @Ilya depends on how many rows you are sorting (sorting is expensive) and how often this query will be run. The way your question is worded suggests that there you do have a problem with the query as it is.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Was there a problem? Error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I just made a sample table and your query seems to work as written:

```
sqlite> create table statuses (word_id, status default -1);
sqlite> insert into statuses (word_id) values (1);
sqlite> insert into statuses (word_id) values (2);
sqlite> insert into statuses (word_id) values (3);
sqlite> insert into statuses (word_id) values (4);
sqlite> insert into statuses (word_id) values (5);
sqlite> select * from statuses;
1|-1
2|-1
3|-1
4|-1
5|-1
sqlite> UPDATE statuses SET status = 0
   ...> WHERE word_id = (
   ...>       SELECT word_id FROM statuses WHERE status = -1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
   ...> );
sqlite> select * from statuses;
1|-1
2|-1
3|0
4|-1
5|-1
```

So, in other words, your query is right - your error is probably elsewhere in your code.